# Best practice handling parameter passed to multiple functions in classes and docstring

Tags: python, function, class

I have a class and multiple functions that run in succession as:

```
class ClassA():
   def __init__(self):
         ....
   def calc_A(self, param1, param2 ,param3):
      res = self.__calc_B(param1=param1)
      res_2 = self.__calc_C(res=res, param2, param3)

   def __calc_B(self, param1):
      return param1**2

   def __calc_C(self, param1):
      return res + param1
```

As you can see `calc_A()` takes in parameters for `__calc_B()` and `__calc_C()`. The original class is getting pretty complex as I need quite a number of parameters to run all the functions and I see myself repeating a lot of docstrings for params that get used in more than one function.

**Question 1:**
Is it best practice to just use *args for `__calc_B()` and `__calc_C()` or should it be handled in a completely different way?

**Question 2:**
Additionally, do I describe the parameters in the docstring in `calc_A()` or in every function?

Answer (score 0):

1. `*args` is never best practice because looking at the function you won't know what is supposed to go into the function. Only by writing documentation to the function can a user figure out what the inputs are supposed to be. Making input parameters explicit if possible is generally favored, because they show up when the user calls `help`.
2. Docstrings mainly serve to help users who can learn what the function does by calling `help(function)`. `__calc_B` and `__calc_C` seem to be functions that are not supposed to be used by the user, so a docstring is not strictly necessary. It is most important to choose good descriptive names for these functions so that you or someone else who needs to understand the code can figure out what it does. You could still write a docstring or comments if it's a particularly difficult function, but they don't need to be so detailed.

If you find no other alternatives, there are ways of generating docstrings dynamically but this is generally not recommended.